# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model_10" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 128, 128, 128, 3), found shape=(32, 128, 128, 3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, valueerror, unet-neural-network

I am trying to train a 3D unet model i got the code for 3D unet model from digital sreeni youtube.
but it is for multiclass semantic segmentation and i have to do is a binary semantic segmentation.
I converted the images into simailar numpy files as he told me in the video with a SHAPE OF `128X128X128X3` .

THIS IS MY MODEL:

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Conv3D, MaxPooling3D, concatenate, Conv3DTranspose, BatchNormalization, Dropout, Lambda
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.metrics import MeanIoU

kernel_initializer =  'he_uniform' #Try others if you want


################################################################
def simple_unet_model(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_DEPTH, IMG_CHANNELS, num_classes):
#Build the model
    inputs = Input((IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_DEPTH, IMG_CHANNELS))
    #s = Lambda(lambda x: x / 255)(inputs)   #No need for this if we normalize our inputs beforehand
    s = inputs

    #Contraction path
    c1 = Conv3D(16, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(s)
    c1 = Dropout(0.1)(c1)
    c1 = Conv3D(16, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c1)
    p1 = MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2))(c1)
    
    c2 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(p1)
    c2 = Dropout(0.1)(c2)
    c2 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c2)
    p2 = MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2))(c2)
     
    c3 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(p2)
    c3 = Dropout(0.2)(c3)
    c3 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c3)
    p3 = MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2))(c3)
     
    c4 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(p3)
    c4 = Dropout(0.2)(c4)
    c4 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c4)
    p4 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2))(c4)
     
    c5 = Conv3D(256, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(p4)
    c5 = Dropout(0.3)(c5)
    c5 = Conv3D(256, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c5)
    
    #Expansive path 
    u6 = Conv3DTranspose(128, (2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(c5)
    u6 = concatenate([u6, c4])
    c6 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(u6)
    c6 = Dropout(0.2)(c6)
    c6 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c6)
     
    u7 = Conv3DTranspose(64, (2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(c6)
    u7 = concatenate([u7, c3])
    c7 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(u7)
    c7 = Dropout(0.2)(c7)
    c7 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c7)
     
    u8 = Conv3DTranspose(32, (2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(c7)
    u8 = concatenate([u8, c2])
    c8 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(u8)
    c8 = Dropout(0.1)(c8)
    c8 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c8)
     
    u9 = Conv3DTranspose(16, (2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(c8)
    u9 = concatenate([u9, c1])
    c9 = Conv3D(16, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(u9)
    c9 = Dropout(0.1)(c9)
    c9 = Conv3D(16, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c9)
     
    outputs = Conv3D(num_classes, (1, 1, 1), activation='sigmoid')(c9)
     
    model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])
    #compile model outside of this function to make it flexible. 
    model.summary()
    
    return model
```

Test if everything is working ok.

```
model = simple_unet_model(128, 128, 128, 3, 1)
print(model.input_shape)
print(model.output_shape)
```

THIS IS THE SHAPE OF MY DATA: 
mask data shape (1, 128, 128, 128, 1)
image data shape (1, 128, 128, 128, 3)

THIS IS HOW I COMPILE THE MODEL:

```
IMG_HEIGHT=image.shape[0]
IMG_WIDTH=image.shape[1]
IMG_DEPTH=image.shape[2]
IMG_CHANNELS=image.shape[3]

model = simple_unet_model(IMG_HEIGHT, 
                              IMG_WIDTH, 
                              IMG_DEPTH, 
                              IMG_CHANNELS, 
                              num_classes=1)`
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

`history=model.fit(image_data, mask_data,
          #steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
          epochs=10,
          verbose=1,
          #validation_data=val_img_datagen,
          #validation_steps=val_steps_per_epoch,
          )
```

I TRIED MODEL.FIT and its giving me this error:

### Epoch 1/10

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-94-ca65b3f26484> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 history=model.fit(image_data, mask_data,
      2           #steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
      3           epochs=10,
      4           verbose=1,
      5           #validation_data=val_img_datagen,

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1050, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 298, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model_10" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 128, 128, 128, 3), found shape=(32, 128, 128, 3)
```

this is my model.summary()

```
Model: "model_2"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_3 (InputLayer)           [(None, 128, 128, 1  0           []                               
                                28, 3)]                                                           
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_38 (Conv3D)             (None, 128, 128, 12  1312        ['input_3[0][0]']                
                                8, 16)                                                            
                                                                                                  
 dropout_18 (Dropout)           (None, 128, 128, 12  0           ['conv3d_38[0][0]']              
                                8, 16)                                                            
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_39 (Conv3D)             (None, 128, 128, 12  6928        ['dropout_18[0][0]']             
                                8, 16)                                                            
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling3d_8 (MaxPooling3D)  (None, 64, 64, 64,   0          ['conv3d_39[0][0]']              
                                16)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_40 (Conv3D)             (None, 64, 64, 64,   13856       ['max_pooling3d_8[0][0]']        
                                32)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 dropout_19 (Dropout)           (None, 64, 64, 64,   0           ['conv3d_40[0][0]']              
                                32)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_41 (Conv3D)             (None, 64, 64, 64,   27680       ['dropout_19[0][0]']             
                                32)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling3d_9 (MaxPooling3D)  (None, 32, 32, 32,   0          ['conv3d_41[0][0]']              
                                32)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_42 (Conv3D)             (None, 32, 32, 32,   55360       ['max_pooling3d_9[0][0]']        
                                64)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 dropout_20 (Dropout)           (None, 32, 32, 32,   0           ['conv3d_42[0][0]']              
                                64)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_43 (Conv3D)             (None, 32, 32, 32,   110656      ['dropout_20[0][0]']             
                                64)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling3d_10 (MaxPooling3D  (None, 16, 16, 16,   0          ['conv3d_43[0][0]']              
 )                              64)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_44 (Conv3D)             (None, 16, 16, 16,   221312      ['max_pooling3d_10[0][0]']       
                                128)                                                              
                                                                                                  
 dropout_21 (Dropout)           (None, 16, 16, 16,   0           ['conv3d_44[0][0]']              
                                128)                                                              
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_45 (Conv3D)             (None, 16, 16, 16,   442496      ['dropout_21[0][0]']             
                                128)                                                              
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling3d_11 (MaxPooling3D  (None, 8, 8, 8, 128  0          ['conv3d_45[0][0]']              
 )                              )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_46 (Conv3D)             (None, 8, 8, 8, 256  884992      ['max_pooling3d_11[0][0]']       
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 dropout_22 (Dropout)           (None, 8, 8, 8, 256  0           ['conv3d_46[0][0]']              
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_47 (Conv3D)             (None, 8, 8, 8, 256  1769728     ['dropout_22[0][0]']             
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_transpose_8 (Conv3DTran  (None, 16, 16, 16,   262272     ['conv3d_47[0][0]']              
 spose)                         128)                                                              
                                                                                                  
 concatenate_8 (Concatenate)    (None, 16, 16, 16,   0           ['conv3d_transpose_8[0][0]',     
                                256)                              'conv3d_45[0][0]']              
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_48 (Conv3D)             (None, 16, 16, 16,   884864      ['concatenate_8[0][0]']          
                                128)                                                              
                                                                                                  
 dropout_23 (Dropout)           (None, 16, 16, 16,   0           ['conv3d_48[0][0]']              
                                128)                                                              
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_49 (Conv3D)             (None, 16, 16, 16,   442496      ['dropout_23[0][0]']             
                                128)                                                              
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_transpose_9 (Conv3DTran  (None, 32, 32, 32,   65600      ['conv3d_49[0][0]']              
 spose)                         64)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 concatenate_9 (Concatenate)    (None, 32, 32, 32,   0           ['conv3d_transpose_9[0][0]',     
                                128)                              'conv3d_43[0][0]']              
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_50 (Conv3D)             (None, 32, 32, 32,   221248      ['concatenate_9[0][0]']          
                                64)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 dropout_24 (Dropout)           (None, 32, 32, 32,   0           ['conv3d_50[0][0]']              
                                64)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_51 (Conv3D)             (None, 32, 32, 32,   110656      ['dropout_24[0][0]']             
                                64)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_transpose_10 (Conv3DTra  (None, 64, 64, 64,   16416      ['conv3d_51[0][0]']              
 nspose)                        32)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 concatenate_10 (Concatenate)   (None, 64, 64, 64,   0           ['conv3d_transpose_10[0][0]',    
                                64)                               'conv3d_41[0][0]']              
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_52 (Conv3D)             (None, 64, 64, 64,   55328       ['concatenate_10[0][0]']         
                                32)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 dropout_25 (Dropout)           (None, 64, 64, 64,   0           ['conv3d_52[0][0]']              
                                32)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_53 (Conv3D)             (None, 64, 64, 64,   27680       ['dropout_25[0][0]']             
                                32)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_transpose_11 (Conv3DTra  (None, 128, 128, 12  4112       ['conv3d_53[0][0]']              
 nspose)                        8, 16)                                                            
                                                                                                  
 concatenate_11 (Concatenate)   (None, 128, 128, 12  0           ['conv3d_transpose_11[0][0]',    
                                8, 32)                            'conv3d_39[0][0]']              
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_54 (Conv3D)             (None, 128, 128, 12  13840       ['concatenate_11[0][0]']         
                                8, 16)                                                            
                                                                                                  
 dropout_26 (Dropout)           (None, 128, 128, 12  0           ['conv3d_54[0][0]']              
                                8, 16)                                                            
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_55 (Conv3D)             (None, 128, 128, 12  6928        ['dropout_26[0][0]']             
                                8, 16)                                                            
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_56 (Conv3D)             (None, 128, 128, 12  17          ['conv3d_55[0][0]']              
                                8, 1)                                                             
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 5,645,777
Trainable params: 5,645,777
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Are you sure the inputs are in the right shape? I tested your code with `image_data = np.zeros((1,128,128,128,3))` and `mask_data= np.zeros((1,128,128,128,1))` and worked without error

Comment: I tried several times and my image shape is as above mentioned. Can you please share the code you used for testing? It would be a great help, thanks in advance delirium78.

Comment: I checked multiple times the problem is that its missing one dimension when being passed to the model using model.fit the image data array that I am passing has the shape of 1x128x128x128x3 in which 1 being the number of images in the array and 128x128x128 is the length width and height, and 3 being the number of channels somehow one of the dimensions I don't know which as all three of them have the same 128 value is being missed can you please share the pipeline that you used for feeding the data into the model for testing. thank you.

Comment: Yes, sure I will share my code, but I only used np.zeros as an input so you should look for the shape mismatch in your input data as it should be 1x128x128x128x3 if you specify so

Answer (score 0):

I used your code to build the model and train it

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Conv3D, MaxPooling3D, concatenate, Conv3DTranspose, BatchNormalization, Dropout, Lambda
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.metrics import MeanIoU
import numpy as np

kernel_initializer =  'he_uniform' #Try others if you want


################################################################
def simple_unet_model(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_DEPTH, IMG_CHANNELS, num_classes):
#Build the model
    inputs = Input((IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_DEPTH, IMG_CHANNELS))
    #s = Lambda(lambda x: x / 255)(inputs)   #No need for this if we normalize our inputs beforehand
    s = inputs

    #Contraction path
    c1 = Conv3D(16, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(s)
    c1 = Dropout(0.1)(c1)
    c1 = Conv3D(16, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c1)
    p1 = MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2))(c1)
    
    c2 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(p1)
    c2 = Dropout(0.1)(c2)
    c2 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c2)
    p2 = MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2))(c2)
     
    c3 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(p2)
    c3 = Dropout(0.2)(c3)
    c3 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c3)
    p3 = MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2))(c3)
     
    c4 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(p3)
    c4 = Dropout(0.2)(c4)
    c4 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c4)
    p4 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2))(c4)
     
    c5 = Conv3D(256, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(p4)
    c5 = Dropout(0.3)(c5)
    c5 = Conv3D(256, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c5)
    
    #Expansive path 
    u6 = Conv3DTranspose(128, (2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(c5)
    u6 = concatenate([u6, c4])
    c6 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(u6)
    c6 = Dropout(0.2)(c6)
    c6 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c6)
     
    u7 = Conv3DTranspose(64, (2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(c6)
    u7 = concatenate([u7, c3])
    c7 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(u7)
    c7 = Dropout(0.2)(c7)
    c7 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c7)
     
    u8 = Conv3DTranspose(32, (2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(c7)
    u8 = concatenate([u8, c2])
    c8 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(u8)
    c8 = Dropout(0.1)(c8)
    c8 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c8)
     
    u9 = Conv3DTranspose(16, (2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(c8)
    u9 = concatenate([u9, c1])
    c9 = Conv3D(16, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(u9)
    c9 = Dropout(0.1)(c9)
    c9 = Conv3D(16, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c9)
     
    outputs = Conv3D(num_classes, (1, 1, 1), activation='sigmoid')(c9)
     
    model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])
    #compile model outside of this function to make it flexible. 
    model.summary()
    
    return model
```

Constructed the model complied it:

```
model = simple_unet_model(128, 128, 128, 3, 1)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.input_shape)
print(model.output_shape)
```

Got the following shapes:

```
(None, 128, 128, 128, 3)
(None, 128, 128, 128, 1)
```

Then I used this as an input:

```
image_data = np.zeros((1,128,128,128,3))
mask_data = np.zeros((1,128,128,128,1))
```

Trained the model with it:

```
history=model.fit(image_data, mask_data,
          #steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
          epochs=10,
          verbose=1,
          #validation_data=val_img_datagen,
          #validation_steps=val_steps_per_epoch,
          )
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/10
1/1 [==============================] - 26s 26s/step - loss: 0.6931 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 2/10
1/1 [==============================] - 23s 23s/step - loss: 0.6926 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 3/10
1/1 [==============================] - 23s 23s/step - loss: 0.6921 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 4/10
1/1 [==============================] - 23s 23s/step - loss: 0.6916 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 5/10
1/1 [==============================] - 23s 23s/step - loss: 0.6911 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 6/10
1/1 [==============================] - 23s 23s/step - loss: 0.6907 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 7/10
1/1 [==============================] - 22s 22s/step - loss: 0.6902 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 8/10
1/1 [==============================] - 22s 22s/step - loss: 0.6897 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 9/10
1/1 [==============================] - 23s 23s/step - loss: 0.6892 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 10/10
1/1 [==============================] - 23s 23s/step - loss: 0.6887 - accuracy: 1.0000
```

Even tried to predict with the model:

```
pred = model.predict(image_data)
pred.shape
```

Output:

```
1/1 [==============================] - 3s 3s/step
(1, 128, 128, 128, 1)
```

Not sure if this helps, let me know if I can help with anything else